# Regex to get text between curly brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on a parser for my program. The parser parses code similar to JSON but I want to stay away from using a JSON parser. It is imperative that I use my own parser and not a third party parser. It uses curly brackets to encase "sets".

This is my current regex code at the moment.

`\\{(\\s*)+(.*?)(\\s*)+\\}`

An example input and output would be:

Input: `{value, value2}`

Output: `value, value2`

Now, this works fine but when I want to put another set in the input:

Input: `{value, {value2}}`

Output: `value, {value2 }<-Outermost curly bracket`

The outermost curly bracket is left behind because the closing curly bracket from the embedded set becomes part of the pattern.

I also want to be able to put other sets in the input:

Input: `{value, value2} {value3, value4}`

(Wanted) Output: `value, value2 value3, value4`

This renders using `$` at the end of the regex practically useless.

Comment: This `{(\s*)+(.*?)(\s*)+}` is a bad way to do it. If dot-all flag is set, the `\s` is redundant. If the dot-all flag is _NOT_ set, this `.*?` will only allow 1 line before it expects optional whitespace then `}`. Kind of defeats the purpose unless you're only trying to match 1 line.

Comment: Regex in Java doesn't support recursion so you can't use it to parse nested structures.

Comment: Use the native Java language recursive function calls, maintain your own counting of braces. Regex in Java is out of the question. Request an upgrade.

Comment: This is ***VERY EMPHATICALLY*** not something you should be doing with regexes. You should use either a JSON parser or a library for parsing context-free grammars (CFGs).

Comment: I'm curious as to where your input is coming from? Also, is there a missing `,` between `value2 value3`?

Comment: @Terminus The input would be coming from a file or user input. And there isn't a missing comma. It's just a different set.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this isn't possible at all. What I did was find the starting point of a set using regex.

The input would be something like:

"`@set1{ value1, value2, @set2{ value3, value4}, @set3{ value5, value6}, value7}        @set4{ value8, value9 }`"

So that would be the equivalent to this outline:

- Set 1

  - Value 1
  - Value 2
  - Set 2

    - Value 3
    - Value 4
  - Set 3

    - Value 5
    - Value 6
  - Value 7
- Set 4

  - Value 8
  - Value 9

What I did next was iterate through each character in the string and counted the number of open brackets. I then made sure that the number of close brackets were equal to one `set`.

I used a recursive method to get nested sets as well.